# Issue with setting div 100% width and height 100%

Tags: css

I want to make width and height of my wrapper div 100% excluding the header and footer.
HTML:

```
<header>
    <h1>This is my heading</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget turpis turpis. Phasellus at urna vitae nibh hendrerit dictum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi semper quam a turpis elementum, vel feugiat nunc fermentum. Nullam semper sapien in magna lobortis, a mattis nunc viverra. Quisque rutrum, dui eget posuere rutrum, diam dolor aliquam felis, eu finibus odio augue a nibh. Curabitur venenatis fermentum diam, tristique fermentum felis tincidunt id. Donec sed venenatis neque, id sollicitudin risus. Donec eu libero non diam blandit tempor.</p>
</div>
<footer>Copyrights syntex</footer>
```

CSS:

```
body{margin:0; padding:0}
header {border-bottom:1px solid green; padding:15px}
.wrapper {border:1px solid red; background:#fafafa; margin:15px; padding:15px; border-radius:4px;}
footer{position:fixed; width:100%; text-align:center; bottom:0; border-top:1px solid #000;}
```

I am looking for pure CSS solution. Irrespective of a content the wrapper div should cover the whole body area excluding header and footer. Appreciate your response.
Here's the jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/eza0fnb2/1/

Comment: Can you please have a look at the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eza0fnb2/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding this part of CSS as the first rule:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
html, body {height: 100%;}
```

And then give a height to the wrapper and set the `position` of the header and footer as `fixed`.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eza0fnb2/3/**

Comment: Okay, did a few changes.

Comment: setting " height: 95%;" to a wrapper will vary height on window resize or in different resolutions.

Comment: @ajay Trying to fix that bug buddy. But other than that, what do you think of the fiddle?

Comment: @ajay Please have a look at the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eza0fnb2/3/. No hardcoded `%`s and no inconsistencies in different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

See this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/dw6s2tkv/)

1. Wrapped all of the elements in .shell and applied [`max-content`](http://demosthenes.info/blog/894/Shrink-Wrap-HTML-containers-with-max-content) in order to keep everything tight.
2. Wrapped the contents of .wrapper with .inner and applied `100vh` and `overflow-y: none` to stretch .wrapper for maximum height.
3. Applied `display: table-cell` to stretch .wrapper for maximum width.

`box-sizing: border-box` should be applied to everything. Apply it to `html`, then make every element and pseudo-element inherit it with`*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }`. That way, if you need to set something to `box-sizing: content-box` default, you have that option.

The unexpected thing about this demo is that if you resize the height, it'll stop short of overlapping the content. If you prefer that the content to continue to be overlapped, set `.inner { overflow-y: hidden; }` Almost forgot, the `position: fixed` on the footer had to go (while writing this, made me realize the overlapping part mentioned previously).

### CSS

```
    /* Styles go here */
html { box-sizing: border-box; height: 100%; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }
body{margin:0; padding:0; height: 100%; }
.shell { max-width: -moz-max-content; max-width: -webkit-max-content; max-width: max-content; }
header {border-bottom:1px solid green; padding:15px}
.wrapper {border:1px solid red; background:#fafafa; margin:15px; padding:15px; border-radius:4px; display: table-cell; }
.inner { display: block; height: 100vh; overflow-y: none; }
footer{ width:100%; text-align:center; bottom:0; border-top:1px solid #000;}
```

### HTML

```
<section class="shell">
<header>
    <h1>This is my heading</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="inner">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget turpis turpis. Phasellus at urna vitae nibh hendrerit dictum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi semper quam a turpis elementum, vel feugiat nunc fermentum. Nullam semper sapien in magna lobortis, a mattis nunc viverra. Quisque rutrum, dui eget posuere rutrum, diam dolor aliquam felis, eu finibus odio augue a nibh. Curabitur venenatis fermentum diam, tristique fermentum felis tincidunt id. Donec sed venenatis neque, id sollicitudin risus. Donec eu libero non diam blandit tempor.</p>
        </div>
</div>
<footer>Copyrights syntex</footer>
</section>
```