# Adjust child div height to be the same as parent/sibling

Tags: css

I'm having a problem that absolutely triggers my OCD to no end and it NEEDS to be fixed.

I'm trying to adjust the .post_author/.post_content divs to be the same height as their parent div, in this case .post

At the moment there is a big ugly space if the post isn't long enough which is as I've said, ugly.
[image]

Post that's long enough:
[image]

Div structure:

```
<div class="post classic">
  <div class="post_author"></div>
  <div class="post_content">
    <div class="post_head></div>
    <div class="post_body></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
    .post {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.post.classic {
    padding-top: 0;
    min-height: 380px;
}

.post .post_author {
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #a1a1a1;
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: normal;
}

.post.classic .post_author {
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 2% 15px 3%;
    margin-top
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: normal;
    border-radius: 0;
    /*box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #000;*/
}

.post.classic .post_content {
    float: right;
    width: 78%;
}

.post_content {
    min-height: 321px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.04);
    padding: 9px 10px 5px 0;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 #000;
}
```

For the life of me I can't figure out how to fix this. I've tried setting the display to table, flex, inline-block, dug up many other similar stackoverflow posts but nothing's worked so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just going on this info, I can only give you limited advice. I assume you're not able to reproduce this into a demo on jsFiddle because the 2 pics look like there's a lot more HTML/CSS than what you've posted. Now that I've cleared that up, I'll just concentrate on making 2 divs fit into another div at max height.

### CSS

```
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.post_content, .post_author { min-height: 380px; height: 100vh; overflow: none; }
```

See my answer on this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734861/issue-with-setting-div-100-width-and-height-100/31735170#31735170), it seems to be similar.

Comment: Mmmh that doesn't fix it. I cannot indeed reproduce this with JsFiddle as the whole code is part of my forum software but if you would be so kind you can check out a live page here demonstrating the problem (with your code added). http://voidgames.net/showthread.php?tid=6

Comment: Thanks, that was very illuminating :) Ok, there's a div.post_body directly over `div.post_cotent`. So it's impossible for `div.author` and `div.post_content` to be at equal heights or even positioned from vertically equal.

Comment: UPDATE: OOPs! sorry, the div.post_content and div.post_author are actually at the same vertical position, but not height. Did you mean you want both of them at the same height? Or do you just want them to be  at the same vertical position? Because both divs on post23 or at `top: 995`

Comment: Actually, div.post_author and div.post_content do not need to be the same height. I just want div.post_body to fill/be the same height as div.post_content, whether there is a div.post_signature or not.

Does that make any sense? I just reset the code to what it was originally btw.

Comment: Give the post_body min-height: 380px or min-height: 100%; height: 100vh or height: 100%

Comment: Alright well after tryng a number of combinations this seems to have fixed it: div.post_body min-height: 32vh !important; height: 100%; It seems like min-height wasn't applying for some reason. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You should make div.post_signature a fixed height since all sigs in forums always specify dimensions for sigs. That'll give you a solid min-height for .post_body. ex. .post_body min-height: 300px and post_sig min-height: 230px

Answer (score 0):

Try setting min-height of post-content to be 100% of the viewport

`min-height: 100vh`

Hope this helps.

Comment: No luck. .post_content stayed the same size. It's like it doesn't pick up the parent div's height?